# How to exclude updatedAt in sequelize when updating row

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

This is a node app. 
I have this function:

```
updateNote: function(noteId, data){
    return models.Note.update(data,
        {
            where: {
                id: noteId
            }
        });
}
```

It is called this way:

```
updateNote(12, {content: 'new content'});
```

This is an ordinary table with ID(integer) and CONTENT(string).
By default, sequelize adds "updatedAt" and "createdAt".
Which is good for my case.

However, each time I runt "updateNote", then the field "updatedAt" is modified to the latest timestamp.
I want it to not be updated.

I have researched a little, with "silent:true" and some other suggestion. But I cannot make it to work. The "updatedAt" is till being updated.
Any advice?

Comment: Hm, I don't think your use case is supported by Sequelize out of the box. This is a hack, but you could provide the existing `updatedAt` time stamp plus `{silent: true}`. e.g., `updateNote(12, {updatedAt: existingValueForUpdatedAt, content: 'new content'}, {silent: true});`

Comment: tried that but still updating with now timestamp :(